# MSQL query for displaying results based on the same keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table called cakes that contains the columns: id, title, description, keywords. I also have a table called keywords, with cakes being the parent. The keywords table contains two columns: id and keyword

I need two queries: ***UPDATED***

1. If a person types in ingredients such as chocolate, hazelnut, strawberry (could be anything separated by a comma) I need the query to search for cakes that contain all three keywords and display results. Display ONLY cakes that contain all three. If no cake matches, I need a message saying nothing found.
2. I have a label on the search box which says, Find similar cakes. If a person types in Vanilla Raspberry or example, the query needs to locate the cake in the database and match its keywords to the keywords of other cakes and display results. Display ONLY cakes that have the same keywords.

Not sure how to write these queries. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how do you if they are similar? can you give sample records in tabular formt? and also your desired result.

Comment: is "keywords" a long text field of delimited strings? Are you have the ability to change this schema?

Comment: Matthew- long text field separated by commas. Example: nuts, peanut butter, chocolate  I really do not want to change the schema- I have several search queries that are working great, but none that display results based on keyword matches

Comment: Change the schema. Or don't bother using an RDBMS for this. It may seem harsh, but it really is that simple.

Answer (score 1):

If the database must use a delimited long-string field for "keywords" rather than putting them in rows, then you will want to use the [LIKE Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Assuming your `[keywords]` column is formatted like this:

'chocolate,ganache,strawberry'

You can search for "similar" cakes like this:

```
SELECT
    columns
FROM
    table t
WHERE
    t.[keywords] LIKE '%chocolate%'
    OR t.[keywords] LIKE '%cheesecake%'
```

Though, if you can change the schema, I would do so. Searching normalized keyword **rows** will be much more efficient and fast than having the DB parse through text using `LIKE`

If you could make a `keywords` **table**, which references the parent table by ID, you could do an equality search using a `JOIN` which would be superior, in my opinion.

It might have three columns: Id, ParentId, Keyword

**EDIT:** So based on your update, you have a `cakewords` table which can be searched.

This is untested, and there is likely a more efficient way using no `IN` clause. But the idea is that you know all the keyword id's for your specific cake. Then you are looking for other cakes having keywords in that collection.

```
SELECT
    columns
FROM
    cake AS cs
JOIN
    cakewords AS csw
        ON csw.[cakeid] = cs.[id]
WHERE
    csw.[wordid] IN
        (SELECT
            cw.[wordid]
        FROM
            cakewords AS cw
        JOIN
            cakes AS c
                ON c.[id] = cw.[cakeid]
        WHERE
            c.[id] = @pMyCurrenctCakeId
        (
```

**EDIT2:** Here is a good related question:

[What's the optimal solution for tag/keyword matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615098/whats-the-optimal-solution-for-tag-keyword-matching)

Based on an answer within, you might try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.[id]
FROM
    cakewords AS cw1
INNER JOIN cakewords cw2 
    ON cw2.[wordid] = cw1.[wordid]
INNER JOIN cake AS c 
    ON c.[id] = cw.[cakeid]
WHERE
    cw1.[cakeid] = @current_cake_id
```

Comment: I do have a keywords table- let me update the code so you can see.

Comment: Matthew- regarding your first option, would I need to use list all keywords in one long query? I have hundreds of keywords.

Comment: @user1913714 you don't, because you have a keywords table. If they were all in a single column then you *might* have had to. Your original description said you had a **column** containing all the keywords. In fact, you have a **table**.

Comment: this may sound ridiculous, but not sure what cs and csw mean there?

Comment: @user1913714 those are aliases for the tables. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: they're just things I made up. c = cakes, cw = cakewords, cs = cakes similar, csw = cakes similar words. Aliases are useful, especially when the same table is used in multiple different ways in a single query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24050/discussion-between-matthew-and-user1913714)